# Cannot remove virbr0 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 last night on my Dell Inspiron desktop computer, and this afternoon I have had trouble connecting to the Internet. 
When I check my connections, it seems like my computer keeps defaulting to a virbr0 connection. It will not allow me to delete it; if I try to delete it, it returns immediately and takes the place of my WiFi connection.
I turned off all libvirt services, but that has not changed the situation.